How to create dynamic routes in NextJs in href param in Link component
I have the following code
import Link from "next/link";

type Country = {
  name: {
    common: string
  },
  region: string
}

export default async function Home() {

  const response = await fetch(`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`);

  const countries = await response.json();

  return (
    <main className="flex min-h-screen flex-col items-center justify-between p-24">
      {
        countries.map((c: Country) => {
          return <Link href={`/countries/${c.name}`}>
            Norway
          </Link>
        })
      }
    </main>
  );
}

Also in my app folder I have folder countries and inside i have [name] folder. I am listing countries and when I click on certain country i want to go to page with more information about this country. When href in Link is hardcoded i mean /countries/Norway for example everything is fine. But when I try to make href dynamic the following error is occured - Error: Dynamic href /users/[object Object] found in  while using the /app router, this is not supported. Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/app-dir-dynamic-href. What is the correct way to do the dynamic routes. Thanks.

if you check the response data from the API call, you'll find an array of countries in this format:
{
  "name": {
    "common": "Moldova",
    "official": "Republic of Moldova",
    "nativeName": {
      "ron": {
        "official": "Republica Moldova",
        "common": "Moldova"
      }
    }
  },
  "tld": [
    ".md"
  ],
  "cca2": "MD",
  "ccn3": "498",
  "cca3": "MDA",
  "cioc": "MDA",
  "independent": true,
  "status": "officially-assigned",
  "unMember": true,
  "currencies": {
    "MDL": {
      "name": "Moldovan leu",
      "symbol": "L"
    }
  }
...
}

In this structure, the name is an object, that's why you get the error  Error: Dynamic href /users/[object Object]. You can access the common name using:
c.name.common

